# Hide Hover content on jquery draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have jquery draggable element whose DOM is:

```
<li class="smartobjects ui-draggable">
<a href="#">sdasd</a>
<div class="popup" style="display: none;">
  <div class="content-heading">sdasd</div>
  <div class="content"><p>null</p></div>
</div>
</li>
```

On hover of smartobject, i am displaying its child div having class `popup`.The problem is,i need to hide this hover div when i drag and drop parent li element. I tried using start and drag event in draggable handle to hide inner popup div. Did not worked though.

Here is the handler:

```
$('.smartobjects').draggable({ containment: "#tblEmailContainer", scroll: false, opacity: 0.7, helper: "clone" });/*mark the smart object as draggable*/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**[Link To Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/180/)**

Comment: would you please add a fiddle ?

Comment: I can't understand if is draggable the li or its parent; can you provide a demo and/or elaborate your demo code?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward :Added link to fiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`start`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) event to hide the popup:

```
/*mark the smart object as draggable*/
$('.smartobjects').draggable({ 
    containment: "#tblEmailContainer", 
    scroll: false, 
    opacity: 0.7, 
    helper: "clone",
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.helper.find('.popup').hide();
    } 
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/PTSkR/181/)**